# Highcharts calculated height on chart on first render incorrect

Tags: jquery, highcharts, height

I'm having trouble with the chart height on render.

The containerDiv's parent div has a set width/height of 960px/540px, and position:absolute.

The CSS -

```
.containerDiv {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15%;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 70%;
}
```

The height value of the containerDiv that is being calculated in the latest highcharts.src.js - approx. on line 11285 - is using jquery's .height() function and is returning: 448px which is approx. 83% of 540, not 378px a.k.a 70%.

I'm instantiating the chart in this fashion:

The JS -

```
var highchart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartObj);
```

This is what the relevant part of chartObj is:

```
Object {
  chart: {
    ...
    renderTo: "containerDiv"
  },
  ...
}
```

The truly weird thing is that right before instantiating the chart, I log out the height of the containerDiv w/ jquery with the expected results of 378px.

Although this doesn't reproduce the issue, here's a fiddle link with the config I described.
http://jsfiddle.net/gbefv/2/

Answer (score 1):

containerContainer in style add position: absolute;

```
<div id="containerContainer" style="position: absolute; width: 960px; height: 540px; margin: 0px;">
```

Comment: #containerContainer is already absolutely positioned. Updated my original question to reflect that. Good suggestion however..

Comment: in your code http://jsfiddle.net/gbefv/2/ containerContainer don't have absolute position .when i add absolute position to containerContainer, $('containerDiv').height() is returning: 378px a.k.a 70%. is that you are ask about ?

Comment: @davedur I agree with radouane, tried to add `position: abosolute` and works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gbefv/3/